# REGEX non-capturing group not working

Tags: php, regex

Data:

> today 13/9 : Aristides, Aristeides, Aristeidis, Kornelios, Kornilios, Kornelia (source : www.namedays.gr)

Regex pattern:

```
/(?:today \d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\s\:\s)([\w[:blank:],]+)(?:\s\(source\s\:\swww\.namedays\.gr\))/
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => today 13/9 : Aristides, Aristeides, Aristeidis, Kornelios, Kornilios, Kornelia (source : www.namedays.gr)
    [1] => Aristides, Aristeides, Aristeidis, Kornelios, Kornilios, Kornelia
)
```

My question is, why my pattern not return only with the names -> Array[1] and why including the non-capturing groups in my result Array[0] also?

I can not figure it out. I'm expecting only Array[1].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0`th capturing group always contains the entire matched text. The first capturing group is always `$1` (or a named).

If it's a problem, you can always `unset()` it.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct. 0-th group is always the entire match, regardless of groups, and the 1st group is the first capturing group result.

E.g., see [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) doc,

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.